# popup window programmaticall

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events

It is possible to create popup window with JavaScript and when it id closed detect whether it was closed by user by `clicked [X]` or by internal JavaScript function? 
something like,

```
var win = window.open("someurl", "popup", "");
var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (win.closed !== false) { 
        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
        detectCloseMethodFunction();
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
confirm("My popup!");
```

This would create a browser popup and you can check for the answer.

Check here for more information: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant events for this question are `onunload` & `onbeforeunload`. But still you cannot detect the pressing of the [X] button of the window through them.